# How to publish in genetics without access to funding or a lab?

Tags: publications, collaboration, projects, biology

I am currently working in quite new university as lecturer for applied medical science undergrad in genetics subjects. I am facing some issues:

- The university requires every lecturer do some publications in their field ( at least 2 papers a year). In genetics, this usually requires access to a lab and good fund for research. However do not have any of those. Any good suggestion ?
- I have been trying for roughly a year and half now to do some collaborations with some scientist who I know, but I face the same issue , they asked if I have funding. I fully understand that to do research or ask for collaboration , I should have either funding, access to a lab or ideas, lab or ideas. I tried to give some proposal, but I have not got any response or some of them might not be interested.

I am thinking now to try to do research based on dry lab projects, but I would need some guidance for that.

I hope i can get some suggestions for these issues .

Thanks in advance

i am

Comment: Do you have an advisor of some kind? The person who offered you the position should have an idea how you are expected to satisfy those requirements.

Comment: unfortunately i do not have. The issue is that the university have regulations that can not be applicable to each school, for instance they ask to have at least one paper or 2 papers during the 4 year as single authors. This is can not be done in genetics filed or medical science filed in general.

Comment: I see.. I am not in that field so I do not have good suggestions. I edited your question to make it more clear what you are asking, maybe that will help you get more answers from people who know. Feel free to roll back the edit (assuming it is approved) if you are not happy with it.

Comment: Which country are you in? This looks like you have a bunch of rules for all lecturers regardless of field that make no sense in some fields, for example in yours.

Comment: Can you "define" your field more broadly? Say "Medical Science" instead of "genetics" specifically. It would open more possibilities.

Comment: I am in Saudi Arabia, you are right. They have some rules which need to be updated.

Comment: Yah that's what I said , medical science  would be easier, but the issue is that they ask in my speciality ( medical genetics). That's fine, but if they give me at least fund